# Button seems to animate instead of the others

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is my UI structure in the Hierarchy:

[image]

And here is how it looks:

[image]

So basically, when I click the first button, its color changes on click as expected. However when I click the second or the third one, the first one also displays the click animation, instead of the one I clicked.

Here are some things I noticed:

- The buttons do register a click as expected.
- When animating the button further than the default (by using custom timeline animations) the behavior is slightly different between the first and the second + third ones.

Things to note:

- I am using a horizontal layout group on the panel with the following settings:
  [image]
- Each button has a TMP image inside with the same size as the button itself.

I theorize that the HLG is the problem here, but I've tried many settings and the result stayed static.

If you need any additional information, **please** ask.

***Turns out the problem was that the target graphic on the buttons were all set to the first one. That's why they still registered the click properly even though the visuals were messed up.***

Comment: "If you need any additional information, please ask." - yes, erm, what is the code that requires a fix? You don't want to fix the layout. You don't want to change the image. That's irrelevant to the animation, isn't it?

Comment: @ThomasWeller No code requires a fix, as no code is linked to the buttons yet. I just want to know why this phenomenon happens, where one button “steals” the other buttons’ onclick animations.

Comment: @CarlosdeAlmeida this would happen if any component of the button that has `RaycastTarget` enabled is bigger then the actual visuals ... maybe something onyour button is too large and receives all the raycasts even though you don't see it ... e.g. make sure there is no `Image` component on your button itself if you anyway have a child `Image` component

Comment: @derHugo turns out the problem was that the target graphic on the buttons were all set to the first one. That's why they still registered the click properly even though the visuals were messed up. Thank you!